# Error: Request failed with status code 403 while creating a compute environment for Production

Tags: salesforce-functions

I was able to create compute environments successfully in sandboxes. When I attempt to do the same for Production:

```
> sf env create compute -o MyOrgAlias -a MyComputeEnv
```

I get:

```
> Creating compute environment for org ID 00D8k000007SNTnRAW... failed
>     Error: Request failed with status code 403
```

I have "Enable Production Space" checked in Production.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate "Production Compute Access" permission in "Functions" permission set (this is in addition to "Compute Access" permission).

When I attempted to enable that, I got an error:

> Can't save permission set Functions, which is assigned to a user with
> user license Cloud Integration User. The user license doesn't allow
> the permission: Compute Production Access

To work around this, I cloned "Functions" permission set and granted "Production Compute Access" and assigned it to the user we set up to access functions feature.

[image]